# Clear input after submit on React Multi Form

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I can't seem to figure out how to clear the input once a new form is switched. I'm able to gather the input from every form and display it at the end, but for some reason information from the first input is shown in the second and third and requires manual deletion. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Form from './Form';
import Results from './Results';

    enter code here

function App() {
    const [state, setState] = useState({
        data: 1,
        Name: '',
        Email: '',
        City: ''
    });

    const nextStep = () => {
        setState({
            ...state,
            data: state.data + 1
        });
    };

    const handleChange = e => {
        setState({ ...state, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
    };

    switch (state.data) {
        case 1:
            return (
                <div className='App-container'>
                    <Form
                        button='Next'
                        nextStep={nextStep}
                        name='Name'
                        state={state.name}
                        handleChange={handleChange}
                    />
                </div>
            );
        case 2:
            return (
                <div className='App-container'>
                    <Form
                        button='Next'
                        nextStep={nextStep}
                        name='Email'
                        state={state.email}
                        handleChange={handleChange}
                    />
                </div>
            );
        case 3:
            return (
                <div className='App-container'>
                    <Form
                        button='Submit'
                        nextStep={nextStep}
                        name='City'
                        state={state.city}
                        handleChange={handleChange}
                    />
                </div>
            );
        case 4:
            return (
                <div className='App-container'>
                    <Results data={state} />
                </div>
            );
        default:
            return 'Error';
    }
}

export default App;


import React from 'react';

const Form = ({ button, nextStep, name, state, handleChange }) => {
    const handleSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        nextStep();
    };

    return (
        <div className='Form-container'>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <input
                    type='text'
                    placeholder={name}
                    name={name}
                    value={state}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                />
                <input type='submit' value={button} />
            </form>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Form;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you are passing `state.name` into your Form components, when it should be `state.Name`, see below:

```
switch (state.data) {
case 1:
    return (
      <div className='App-container'>
          <Form
            button='Next'
            nextStep={nextStep}
            name='Name'
            state={state.name} // < --------- This should be state.Name
            handleChange={handleChange}
          />
      </div>
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's because you're not actually resetting your state when calling `nextStep()`.

You're just merging new `data` but the other values: `Name`, `Email`, `City` stay the same

Fix:

```
const nextStep = () => {
        setState({
            data: state.data + 1,
            Name: '',
            Email: '',
            City: ''
        });
    };
```